# Adding custom code to <head> in Drupal

Tags: drupal, head

I'm trying to figure out where the `<head>` for all of the pages in Drupal is (I'm using Orange theme if it matters). I have to add analytics code into the `<head>`.

Inside which file would I find the `<head>`?

Comment: please add anything related to the head in html.tpl.php which is available in your themes folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in your theme folder you'll see `page.tpl.php`, that is the template for the site.  You can add the code there most likely.

Comment: i think so html.tpl.php is the right file instead of page.tpl.php

Answer (score 8):

Use [`drupal_set_html_head()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_set_html_head/6) by placing this in your themes *template.php* file. If the function `MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_page()` already exists insert what is inside the `{`closure`}` brackets below (before the `$vars['head']` if that exists in it as well) :

```
function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  // say you wanted to add Google Webmaster Tools verification to homepage.
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    drupal_set_html_head('<meta name="google-site-verification" content="[string from https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification]" />');
    $vars['head'] = drupal_get_html_head();
  }
}
```

Comment: This no longer works in Drupal 7 - $vars['head'] does not exists.

Comment: Furthermore :) drupal_set_html_head() has been renamed to drupal_add_html_head() in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4):

In *template.php* of your theme folder :

```
function your_theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {  

    $appleIcon57px = array(
        '#tag' => 'link',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
            'href' => '/images/ICONE-57.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'media' => 'screen and (resolution: 163dpi)'
        )
    );
    drupal_add_html_head($appleIcon57px, 'apple-touch-icon57');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One another solution is to use blocks in header these can also managed very effectively using css.

1. All you have to do is to go to Structure->Blocks then create new block.
2. Then select theme corresponding to it and position in which section you want to show that block.
3. Custom html like   can be added. And can be handled from that id.

It allow me to handle page structure very easily.

Answer (score 0):

In the *theme folder* (e.g. `themes/orange`) there is a `templates` folder with the file `html.tpl.php`

In this file you can freely add what you need to the `head` section and it will be added to every page.